Total Capacity and Effort of all the teams in ADO across all Iterations
We are following SAFe
How can I know the Total capacity and Total Effort of all the teams in ADO across multiple Iterations(Lest say 5 Iterations) or a PI?
I am aware that, Capacity of a Team can be known from the Sprint->Backlog Tab in ADO.
Lets say, There are in total 2 teams and I need to know the Total Capacity of Teams across all iterations.
Similarly, I need to also know the Total Hours the teams have planned across all iterations.
For Example:
Team 1 has Capacity of 100 Hours in Iteration 1
Lets say, they have planned 80 hours(Sum of original estimates across all Tasks).
Team 1 has Capacity of 100 Hours in Iteration 2.
Lets say, they have planned 90 hours(Sum of original estimates across all Tasks)
Similarly, Team 2 has Capacity of 100 Hours in Iteration 1.
Lets say, they have planned 80 hours(Sum of original estimates across all Tasks).
Team 2 has Capacity of 100 Hours in Iteration 2.
Lets say, they have planned 90 hours(Sum of original estimates across all Tasks)
I need to know that the below:
Total capacity of all the teams across the 2 Iterations is 400 Hours(200 from Team 1 and 200 from Team 2) and Effort planned is 340 Hours(170 from Team 1 and 170 from Team 2).
How can I get this data in ADO?
Can you please help me with possible inputs?

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can show the Total Capacity and Effort of all the teams in Azure DevOps across all Iterations.
Currently, Azure DevOps UI can only display information about a single iteration of a single team (including total capacity).
I have checked the Rest APIs(e.g. Capacities - Get Capacities With Identity Ref And Totals), it only supports showing the capacity per member and total capacity per day instead the entire iteration.
For example:

Therefore, we cannot achieve the requirements through Rest APIs.
Apart from this, I also checked the analysis view(e.g. PowerBI chart) and extensions. They also do not support integration with Azure DevOps Team Capacity.
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community which is our main forum for product suggestions to report this feature.

Thank you Kevin for clarity, will request the Developer Community
